# objective c : make UIPickerView separator line invisible

Tags: objective-c, uipickerview

i create a pickerView with this codes(separator line is invisible):

```
pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 40, [Functions Dwidth], 190)];
    pickerView.delegate = self;
    pickerView.dataSource = self;
    pickerView.layer.borderWidth = 0;
    [popupView addSubview:pickerView];
.
.
.

-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView{
    return 3;
}

-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    return 10;
}

-(UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view{
    .
    .
    return someView;
}
```

after i added this codes to my project separator line is going to visible:

```
[pickerView selectRow:3 inComponent:1 animated:NO];
[pickerView selectRow:2 inComponent:0 animated:NO];
```

how i can make it invisible again?

Comment: Are you testing in a simulator? I don't think the separators were ever invisible other than an artifact of viewing a scaled simulator.

Comment: No i'm not using simulator